# Applying a 1D convolution for 4D input

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, python, computer-vision, tensorflow

i'm trying to implement this [paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~urtasun/publications/luo_etal_cvpr18.pdf) and I'm stuck for quite some time now. Here is the issue:

I have a 3D tensor and has  `(180,200,20)` as dimension and I'm trying to append 5 of them as the paper states:

> Now that each frame is represented as a 3D tensor, we can append multiple frames’ along a new temporal dimension to create a 4D tensor

what I did is I applied the tensorflow command `tf.stack()` and now so far so good, I have my input as a 4D tensor and has `(5,180,200,20)` as stated in the paper:

> Thus our input is a 4 dimensional tensor consisting of time, height, X and Y

Now what I'm trying to do is to apply a 1D convolution on this 4D tensor as the paper mentions:

> given a 4D input tensor, we first use a 1D convolution with
>   kernel size n on temporal dimension to reduce the temporal dimension from n to 1

is this case n = 5.

And here where I got stuck, I created the kernel as follow:

`kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5,16,16], dtype = tf.float64, stddev = 1e-1, name = 'weights'))`

and tried to apply a 1D convolution:

`conv = tf.nn.conv1d(myInput4D, kernel, 1 , padding = 'SAME'`)

and I get this error

`Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 5 for 'conv1d_42/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [5,180,1,200,20], [1,5,16,16]`

I don't understand how `1` is added to the dimensions at the `index = 2` and `index = 0` in the first and second tensors.

I also tried this:

`conv = tf.layers.conv1d(myInput4D, filters = 16, kernel_size = 5, strides = 1, padding = 'same)`

And get the following error:

`Input 0 of layer conv1d_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [5, 180, 200, 20]`

My question is: Is it possible to apply a 1D convolution on a 4D input and if yes can anyone suggests a way to do so? Because in the Tenssorflow documentations it says the input must be 3D

> tf.nn.conv1d(
>       value=None,
>       filters=None,
>       stride=None,
>       padding=None,
>       use_cudnn_on_gpu=None,
>       data_format=None,
>       name=None,
>       input=None,
>       dilations=None
>   )
>
> value: A 3D Tensor. Must be of type float16, float32, or float64.

Thank you.

Comment: I want to ask you if you found a solution as I am in the same problem.